# (Linux) Unable to link archives via cmake

Tags: cmake

On the command line, the following produces an executable:

```
g++ -o a.out main.cpp class1.cc class2.cc /usr/lib/libgsl.a /usr/lib/libgslcblas.a
```

However I am unsure how to get cmake to work properly. 
When I add a line like

```
include_directories(/usr/lib/)
link_libraries(usr/lib/libgsl.a usr/libgslcblas.a)
```

the configuring seems to work but building fails:

```
CMakeFiles/kmv.dir/main.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:27: undefined reference to `gsl_matrix_alloc'
main.cpp:35: undefined reference to `gsl_matrix_fscanf'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [kmv] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/kmv.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
*** Failed ***
```

Seems to be a synthax problem. Any hint is welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of

```
include_directories(/usr/lib)
link_libraries(usr/lib/libgsl.a usr/libgslcblas.a)
```

try

```
add_executable (targetName main.cpp class1.cc class2.cc)
target_link_libraries(targetName gsl gslcblas)
```

Where *targetName* is the name of the output binary you intend to create. The path `/usr/lib` should already be in the default library search path for CMake, so you shouldn't have to specify that, but if you did have to specify a custom library path, you would do it like so

```
link_directories(/some/custom/library/path)
```

The `include_directories` CMake directive is used for adding header search paths, not library search paths...

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works (with cblas replaced by gslcblas). Indeed, it is not necessary to specify the path /usr/lib. Strange enough, for the command line stuff (g++ -o ...) it is necessary to specify it.

Comment: Glad to help -- now, knowing that this solution works, would you kindly accept the answer? :D

Comment: Thanks, your answer is the right one. What should I do to (formally?) accept it? Besides, it is not necesary to specify the classes in the CmakeLists.txt. add_executable(target main.cpp) does already the job.

Comment: Read the faq regarding asking questions, particularly the last part concerning how to answer questions -- http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 4):

Probably, link_libraries is deprecated
http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2009-April/028439.html

Try using target_link_libraries instead.

Comment: Not to be off topic, but how did this answer receive the bounty I posted?  It was pretty clear months ago that my answer below was at least unofficially accepted by the OP (see the comments).

Comment: Even I did not understood that. Only plus point in my answer was formal mail on cmake domain.

Comment: Ok, got the answer to @hatboyzero's question: [ From http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty _If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with at least 2 upvotes will be awarded half the bounty amount._ Since YOU had posted the bounty, you cannot get it to yourself. Only other answer matching the criterion was my answer. ]

Comment: I didn't realize that the bounty could not be awarded to the originating party.  Thanks :-)